# App.OnExit no suitable method found to override when adding ResourceDirectory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I've came across this error, which I couldn't find the solution for. I'm implementing an mvvm application and in main window I'm setting the main DataContext in xaml using a loader:
in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
       <viewModel:KinectViewModelLoader x:Key="KinectViewModelLoader"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="KinectFittingRoom.MainWindow"
...
        DataContext="{Binding KinectViewModel, Source={StaticResource KinectViewModelLoader}}">
...
</Window>
```

Everything was running well, but now I wanted to add some dynamic resources, so I've created some xaml files containing styles and other elements.
In example:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ModelUIElement3D x:Key="BirthdayHatModel">
...
    </ModelUIElement3D>
</ResourceDictionary >
```

To use them in MainWindow.xaml I've added them to App.xaml file as ResourceDirectory and then my application began to crash.

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="KinectFittingRoom.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:KinectFittingRoom.ViewModel"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <viewModel:KinectViewModelLoader x:Key="KinectViewModelLoader"/>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ResourceDictionary">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/GlassButton.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Models/BirthdayHat.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And now I'm getting an error on App.xaml.cs file saying that `KinectFittingRoom.App.OnExit(System.Windows.ExitEventArgs)` has no suitable method to override.

My overriden method:

```
protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
{
    KinectViewModelLoader.Cleanup();
    base.OnExit(e);
}
```

Mabe someone could explain to me why adding ResourceDirectory node causes my application to throw an error? What can I do to include those resources and avoid such problem? I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change two things in your XAML:

1. In your App.xaml file Move the declaration of your ViewModel inside ResourceDictionary section. Also if possible you should delete x:Key="ResourceDictionary". So now your App.xaml should look like:

   ```
   <Application x:Class..................>
       <Application.Resources>
           <ResourceDictionary>
               <viewModel:KinectViewModelLoader x:Key="KinectViewModelLoader"/>
               <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/GlassButton.xaml"/>
                   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Models/BirthdayHat.xaml"/>
               </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           </ResourceDictionary>
       </Application.Resources>
   </Application>
   ```
2. If after following the above step your program does not work then please follow this step along. Change the DataContext Property of your window like the code shown below:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="KinectFittingRoom.MainWindow"
           DataContext="{StaticResource KinectViewModelLoader}">
       ...
   </Window>
   ```
3. If still your application does not work then change the order of the lines in App.OnExit() as follows:

   ```
   protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnExit(e);
       KinectViewModelLoader.Cleanup();
   }
   ```

Comment: The first step worked for me. I deleted the x:Key attribute and moved the loader node inside the ResourceDictionary. Can you tell me please, does putting just one node inside `<Application.Resources>` create the dictionary by default?